# conversion from hexadecimal to binary

Tags: c

I am trying to display a binary string out of hexadecimal string. my code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char hexa[5], num[120];
    int i = 0, j, k, t;
    char ch;
    printf("enetr hexadecimal");
    while (ch = getchar() != '\n') {
        scanf("%c", &ch);
        hexa[i] = ch;
        i++;
    }
    k = 0;
    for (j = 0; hexa[j] != '\0'; j++) {
        if (hexa[j] == 'A') {
            num[k++] = '1';
            num[k++] = '0';
            num[k++] = '1';
            num[k++] = '0';
        } else if (hexa[j] == 'B') {
            num[k++] = '1';
            num[k++] = '0';
            num[k++] = '1';
            num[k++] = '1';
        } else if (hexa[j] == 'C') {
            num[k++] = '1';
            num[k++] = '1';
            num[k++] = '0';
            num[k++] = '0';
        } else if (hexa[j] == 'D') {
            num[k++] = '1';
            num[k++] = '1';
            num[k++] = '0';
            num[k++] = '1';
        } else if (hexa[j] == 'E') {
            num[k++] = '1';
            num[k++] = '1';
            num[k++] = '1';
            num[k++] = '0';
        } else if (hexa[j] == 'F') {
            num[k++] = '1';
            num[k++] = '1';
            num[k++] = '1';
            num[k++] = '1';
        } else if (hexa[j] == '0') {
            num[k++] = '0';
            num[k++] = '0';
            num[k++] = '0';
            num[k++] = '0';
        } else if (hexa[j] == '1') {
            num[k++] = '0';
            num[k++] = '0';
            num[k++] = '0';
            num[k++] = '1';
        } else if (hexa[j] == '2') {
            num[k++] = '0';
            num[k++] = '0';
            num[k++] = '1';
            num[k++] = '0';
        } else if (hexa[j] == '3') {
            num[k++] = '0';
            num[k++] = '0';
            num[k++] = '1';
            num[k++] = '1';
        } else if (hexa[j] == '4') {
            num[k++] = '0';
            num[k++] = '1';
            num[k++] = '0';
            num[k++] = '0';
        } else if (hexa[j] == '5') {
            num[k++] = '0';
            num[k++] = '1';
            num[k++] = '0';
            num[k++] = '1';
        } else if (hexa[j] == '6') {
            num[k++] = '0';
            num[k++] = '1';
            num[k++] = '1';
            num[k++] = '0';
        } else if (hexa[j] == '7') {
            num[k++] = '0';
            num[k++] = '1';
            num[k++] = '1';
            num[k++] = '1';
        } else if (hexa[j] == '8') {
            num[k++] = '1';
            num[k++] = '0';
            num[k++] = '0';
            num[k++] = '0';
        } else if (hexa[j] == '9') {
            num[k++] = '1';
            num[k++] = '0';
            num[k++] = '0';
            num[k++] = '1';
        }
    }
    for (t = 0; num[t] != '\0'; t++)
        printf("%c", num[t]);
    return 0;
}
```

This snippet is only displaying from the first character of hexadecimal string not the whole string. please help in what is causing the error and help me rectify the same

Comment: You have multiple problems with the presented code. To start with the loop reading input, you don't have any boundary checks, you don't check that the input is valid, th eloop condition is not what you expect it to be (read about [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)) and you read two characters of input in each iteration of the loop. You then in the next loop look for the string terminator in the `hexa` array, but you don't actually add it to the array.

Comment: And finally, with the help of [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) you can easily trim the code down to probably around ten lines or so.

Comment: Don't use `scanf` inside `while`, you do not need it, it is redundant. You already read the character from console using `getchar()`...

Comment: the receiving string 'hexa' should be pre-initialized to all 0x00  The developed string 'num' should be pre-initialized to all 0x00

Comment: the code does not allow for the lower case characters a,b,c,d,e,f

Comment: the function getchar() returns an integer, so use integer and extract the lower 8 bits for the hex character.

Comment: the  value '\n' can be two characters, so, on certain OS's comparing to a single char will fail.

Answer (score 3):

You're (for some reason) processing this as text, which is very much more complicated than doing it as actual numbers.

You could get away with something like:

```
unsigned int hexa;

if(scanf(" %x", &hexa) == 1)
{
  int i;
  for(i = (CHAR_BIT * sizeof hexa) - 1; i >= 0; --i)
  {
    putchar('0' + ((hexa & (1u << i)) != 0));
  } 
  putchar('\n');
}
```

The above will always generate a fixed (probably 32-bit) width of the binary, you can do it differently if you really want a variable-length binary number.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you-

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        unsigned int num;
        int i, j;

        printf("Enter an Hex number\n");
        if(scanf(" %x", &num)!=1){
        printf("Enter proper Hexadecimal number\n");
        return 0;
        }
        printf("%x in binary format is- \n", num);
        for (i = 31; i >= 0; i--)
        {
                if ((num>>i)&1)
                        printf("1");
                else
                        printf ("0");
        }
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
}
```